# Let $a_1,...,a_k > 0$. Show that nth root of $\sqrt{a^n_1 + ...+a^n_n} \to max(a^n_1...a^n_n)$ as $n$ → +∞.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_1,...,a_k > 0$. Show that $\sqrt[n]{a^n_1 + ...+a^n_n} \to \max(a_1...a_k)$ as $n$ → +∞.

I tried writing out cases to realize a pattern. I know that the limit is less than what is inside the root. I also tried using logs then ratio test, but to no avail. I also know that the limit is $> 0$

Answer (score 1):

Use the squeeze theorem: Let W.L.O.G. $a_1 = \max\{a_1,...,a_k\}$. Then $$\sqrt[n]{a_1^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{a_1^n+...+a_k^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{na_1^n}$$
Can you pick it up from here?